# embed an video in website that should play from middle

Tags: html

I want to embed an video in my website that should be played from middle(vedio duration:2 mins, want to make it play from 1 min instead of starting) in html

Comment: What have you tired?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a bit of javascript to set the starting time before the video plays.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("VideoID");
vid.currentTime = 60; //60 seconds for the 1 minute mark
```